# After deploy to firebase, changes in browser will not update without deleting site cache in browser

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

Instead of asking all users to delete their cache when an update is pushed, is there a script I can add to my app so that when the site is loaded it deletes the existing cache for the site?

I could remove the script when the app is complete but for development and testing purposes I deploy (or serve locally) multiple times a day, its a pain to have to delete my cache every time.

An even bigger pain is trying to get others to delete cache when I tell them the site has been updated and I need feedback.

Thanks

EDIT: After much searching I think this [How to remove a service worker registered in previous deploy from users' browsers with the newly deployed version of site (Firebase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157823/how-to-remove-a-service-worker-registered-in-previous-deploy-from-users-browser?rq=1) is similar to what the problem is, but the answers are not specific. It looks like the issue might be with a service worker but I am unsure how to implement a fix.

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding what you're talking about here, and how it relates to Firestore, as you've tagged the question.

Comment: my site uses the cloud firestore database.

Comment: So, what are you deploying?  What do you mean by "site cache"?  What's the script that you've written?

Comment: Im asking if there is a way to see the updated page hosted on firestore without wiping the cache; If not, is it possible to make a script to wipe the browsers site cache when you first connect to the site.

Comment: I think this question is more related to firebase hosting, and not so much firestore if I understand?

Comment: Firestore doesn't host "pages".  It stores "documents".  I'm still having a hard time understanding what it is you're observing and how it relates to Firestore.

Comment: I tagged firestore because thats the database im using for the site hosted on firebase, if thats wrong I can delete the tag. I have a react app that im deploying to firebase via the CLI. When i make an edit to the app and deploy (or serve locally) then visit the site, the changes won't be seen because the browser is using the cached version of the site. To fix this you Ctrl+shift+i and hit "Clear Site Data". My question is that this is tedious for my customer to do, so is there a script or command i can add to my react app or html page that will clear the site cache when the browser connects.

Comment: I actually think your question is good. Strictly speaking it probably has nothing to do with reactjs as well. Maybe you can rephrase the question to something like this: When using firebase-hosting and publishing a static web-app, is it somehow possible for users that have already loaded the application to get the newest version, without them having to hard browser-reload?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase deploy not updating JS file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192901/firebase-deploy-not-updating-js-file)

Comment: @DauleDK I just found this [How to remove a service worker registered in previous deploy from users' browsers with the newly deployed version of site (Firebase)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48157823/how-to-remove-a-service-worker-registered-in-previous-deploy-from-users-browser?rq=1) which seems similar but I cant tell how to implement it

Comment: Hmm, I will try to look at it. I think I would probably try to solve the problem, by listening to a firestore node with the version, and when this version number is changed, hard reload?

Comment: You could maybe look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099201/javascript-hard-refresh-of-current-page

Comment: One way to solve your problem is to use html-webpack-plugin (or webpack's built-in hashing ability), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36481216/caching-issue-with-web-application-developed-using-reactjs-webpack. By default, Javascript bundle file and css keep the same file names when you re-build, hence the caching done by the browser. The problem is not really related to Firebase Hosting, you would encounter it with any other hosting platform. And it is also classic with SPA frameworks, for example Vue.js.